# Kibana creates monitoring indexes automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

A few days ago I was testing kibana and exploring its characteristics. When I entered http://localhost/_cat/indices?v I saw some strange indexes and when I deleted them, they were recreated automatically.

```
health status index                           uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2018.11.17     23zMdQcuSeeZRmQ8yzD-Qg   1   0      86420          192     33.9mb         33.9mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2018.11.16     Dn7WCVBUTZSSaBlKKy8hxA   1   0      12283           69      5.8mb          5.8mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2018.11.18     YaFbgQIiTVGZ1kjOB_wWpA   1   0      95069          250     36.6mb         36.6mb
green  open   .monitoring-es-6-2018.11.19     3bvTjlk0SNy2UR21C1muVA   1   0      62104          208     32.4mb         32.4mb
green  open   .monitoring-kibana-6-2018.11.16 MXwi2p83S46tEglvViIUUQ   1   0         12            0     32.6kb         32.6kb
green  open   .kibana                         MZXJrrajQvqAL9h1rKuxWg   1   0          1            0        4kb            4kb
... my other indexes
```

How to prevent these indices from being created?

Comment: Check this https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/68017.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [disable monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-monitoring.html) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file:

```
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```

The [same thing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/configuring-monitoring.html) in `kibana.yml`:

```
xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
```